# C# Data Annotation

Tags: c#, data-annotations

I want to define data annotations other where except top of property name. I know I can write my codes like this:

```
public class student
{
   [Required]
   public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

But I'm using Linq to Sql data classes and I don't want to change these classes. I know I can define a new class just with data annotations but I want to know is there an else way?
Sorry for poor english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have your `DataAnnotations` attributes either decorating the members of the class. Or they can be in a metadata buddy-class. [Here](http://hartzer.wordpress.com/2010/01/26/mvc-buddy-class/) is an article explaining that approach.

But since your actual class needs to be decorated with `MetadataType` I do not know if this can be accomplished using Linq-To-Sql.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add your data annotations in a different file:

Application start:

```
protected void Application_Start()
        {
            //...
            MetadataExtensions.Register();
        }
```

Register:

```
public static class MetadataExtensions
{
    private static void Register(Type type, Type associatedMetadataType)
    {
        var provider = new AssociatedMetadataTypeTypeDescriptionProvider(type, associatedMetadataType);
        TypeDescriptor.AddProviderTransparent(provider, type);
    }

    public static void Register()
    {
        Register(typeof(Student), typeof(StudentMetadata));
    }
}
```

Specify your annotations in this file (no need to redeclare all your properties, only those with annotations):

```
public class StudentMetadata
{
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```